# Regression discontinuity plot using ggplot with binned running variable (x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, regression

I wish to create a regression discontinuity plot using ggplot (I don't wish to use any other package) such that the points that show up on the plot should correspond to binned x-values, rather than for all available x-values.

I have written the following code and obtained the plot linked below after the code (sorry, I can't share my data set because it is restricted). However, the points that show up are conditional means for ALL x-values. **How do I get the points to show conditional means for only 5 bins on either side of zero (the cutoff)? Also, I don't want the x-axis to show groups of the running variable as in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296789/ggplot-add-regression-line-on-a-boxplot-with-binned-non-continuous-x-axis) question. I want the x-axis to be continuous, yet I want points for binned data. I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071944/ggplot2-geom-point-with-binned-x-axis-for-binary-data) question but it didn't solve my problem.**

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>% dplyr::filter(absolute_running_var<0.10)%>%
  # Group the data by running_var then get means
  group_by(running_var) %>% 
  mutate(mean_outcome_var = mean(outcome_var))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(y = outcome_var, x = running_var)) +
  #geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  # Points for the means
  geom_point(data = mydata, 
             # Specify aesthetics
             mapping = aes(y = mean_outcome_var, x = running_var), 
             size = 0.5) +
  
  # Add a line based on a linear model for the people scoring 0 or less
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mydata, running_var <= 0), method = "lm") + 
  # Add a line based on a linear model for the people scoring more than 0
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mydata, running_var > 0), method = "lm") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  labs(x = "running_var", y = "outcome_var", color = "") + ggtitle("TITLE") + theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU5Fx.png)

Comment: If you need more help than that, please include a dummy data set in your question since you don't want to include the real data (though to be fair, the plot already shows us your data, so it's not clear why you can't share the output from `dput(mydata[c("running_var", "outcome_var")]`

Comment: @AllanCameron, thank you fo your comment! While it is helpful in moving closer to what I want, it still produces multiple points for a given x-bin rather than a single mean point: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20231127142208/https://i.ibb.co/KLfCTqp/rd.png)

Comment: Try `geom_point(data = mydata %>% mutate(groups = cut(running_var, breaks = seq(-0.1, 0.1, 0.02))) %>% group_by(groups) %>% reframe(running_var = seq(-0.09, 0.09, 0.02), outcome_var = mean(outcome_var))`

Comment: We really do need a reproducible example to test and verify code though.